# Jquery Datatables adding parameter to request

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, datatable

My problem is that i cannot add a parameter to my request without overwriting the other request parameters.

#### Example

```
var table = $('#datatable').DataTable({
"bServerSide": true,
"bProcessing": true,
 "ajax": {
 "url": "/../",
    "data": function ( d ) {
        return $.extend( {}, d, {
            "iLocked": "this is the only thing i receive"
        } );
    }
},
........
```

For refference:

> https://datatables.net/reference/option/ajax.data (tried all examples)

The code above nulls all other request parameters that I previously received, like:

```
sEcho,
sSearch,
iDisplayLength,
iDisplayStart,
iColumns, 
iSortingCols
sColumns
```

I need both those requests and my iLocked property.

I also tried this:

```
fnServerParams: function (aoData) {
        aoData.iLocked = { "name":"iLocked","value":"I don't know where to receive this"};
    },
```

In this case I don't know where to receive this parameter.

***Receiving parameters: I receive my parameters in two ways:***

1. Controller parameters:  public ActionResult AjaxHandler(TableParams
   param,string iLocked)
2. Request: var customParam= Request.Params.Get("iLocked");*

**My basic setup looks like this:**

> https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/155422/jQuery-DataTables-and-ASP-NET-MVC-Integration-Part#Implementation

My `jQueryDataTableParamModel` also has the iLocked property.

## Question

How do I receive both my new parameter without nulling the previous parameters?

## Answer

```
 "sAjaxSource": "/../",        
    "fnServerParams": function (aoData) {
        aoData.push( { "name": "iLocked", "value": "my_value" } );
    }
```

Credit: [Sending data to the server with fnServerParams and aoData for jquery DataTable does not work in MVC4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20349593/sending-data-to-the-server-with-fnserverparams-and-aodata-for-jquery-datatable-d)

Patrick

Comment: Another link: 
https://www.datatables.net/release-datatables/examples/server_side/custom_vars.html

Comment: Solution found in this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20349593/sending-data-to-the-server-with-fnserverparams-and-aodata-for-jquery-datatable-d